# Android - compare between button background to Resource

Tags: android, android-layout, android-components

I'm trying to compare between button background to resource file.
For exmaple, I have button

**BUTTON**

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGenre"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_genre"
        android:text="POST"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"/>
```

The background has `drawable/frame_genre`. I'm trying to compare this background with Resouce file.

**For example**

```
Drawable btnBackground = holder.btnGenre.getBackground();
if(btnBackground.getConstantState() == (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.frame_genre).getConstantState())){
                   Toast.makeText(context, "WORKED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
```

Well this `if` statement check what background the button has. If its `frame_genre` then it should continue to the block.

In my case the background Button is `frame_genre` and the `if` statement should be TRUE.
But for some reason when i log the Button background `Log.d(TAG, btnBackground.getConstantState().toString());` and the `frame_genre`  `Log.d(TAG,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.frame_genre).getConstantState())`

It printing two diffrent memory locations.

I cant understand why, after all, I'm pointing to the same file which is `frame_genre`.
Can anyone explain to me whats the diffrent?

And I'm looking for a way to check the Button because i want to change its background once it clicked.

Comment: Why don't you use selector for clicked and non clicked state?

Comment: Never heared about it. Can you please direct me where should i look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create selector in drawable it's a xml file. Give your different images as drawable for the state like pressed, normal or selected, etc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btnGenre_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btnGenre_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btnGenre_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

Give this xml as background to your button.

```
        <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnGenre"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_xml_name"
    android:text="POST"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Programatically write below code on clickListner on your btnGenre,

```
if (Objects.equals(btnGenre.getBackground().getConstantState(), this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btnGenre_selected).getConstantState()))
{
   star.setBackground(R.drawable.btnGenre_normal);
}else {
  star.setBackground(R.drawable.btnGenre_selected);
}
```

Comment: Alright, and there is a way so i can check programmlly if the current Button has a `btnGenre_selected` or `btnGenre_pressed`?  **EDIT** I should use `(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.frame_genre).getConstantState()` right?

Comment: If you want to achieve it programmatically then yes you need to use ConstantState of drawable. I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it

Comment: Still not working. The `if` statement return always false. Its still pointing to diffrent memory location. The button background and the `getResources()`

Comment: Well i dont think it will work becuase this Button, I'm creating in a Recycler view. I have 9 Buttons, so i think each Button gets its own location memory. But still it doesn't make any sense becuase I have only one Drawable file and i point each Button to that Drawable file. I think I'm missing here something